# properties of partial sums of series $\sum \sin(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

There have been many questions posted here about the sequence $s(x)_n = \sin(nx)$ and its corresponding series $S(x)$. In particular, it has been shown that $s(x)_n$ only converges if $x$ is a multiple of $\pi$ and moreover that its $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ for almost all $x$ are $1$ and $-1$, respectively. It follows immediately that the corresponding series does not converge if $x$ is not a multiple of $\pi$.

A related but separate questions is for which $x$ $\liminf S(x)$ and $\limsup S(x)$ are finite (treating the series $S(x)$ as a sequence of partial sums). Moreover, for which $x$ do these partial sums go between positive and negative infinitely often?

I am wondering to what degree one can draw a parallel between the terms $S(x)_n$ and a uniform one-dimensional random walk, which crosses 0 infinitely often but also goes arbitrarily far in the positive and negative directions.

Comment: "for which x liminf S_n(x) and limsup S_n(x) exist" Obviously, for every x.

Comment: I mean for which they are finite. I will edit the question.

Comment: Yes, and the answer is the same: obviously, always.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating? I know that the the ratio of the magnitudes of posive terms to negative terms in the series asymptotically approaches $1$ but that doesn't imply that the absolute difference remains bounded.

Comment: It happens that one can compute explicitely every partial sum, simply write each sine as the imaginary part of a complex exponential and sum geometric finite sums.

Comment: Can't you compose an answer yourself, based on my indications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$S_N(\alpha)\triangleq\sum_{n=0}^{N}\sin(n\alpha) = \frac{\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}-\cos\frac{(2N+1)\alpha}{2}}{2\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}}$$
(we can prove this identity by multiplying both sides by $2\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}$ and exploiting the fact that $2\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\sin(n\alpha)=\cos((n-1/2)\alpha)-\cos((n+1/2)\alpha)$ leads to a telescopic sum)
hence, if $\frac{\alpha}{\pi}$ is an irrational number, by the density of $e^{iN\alpha}$ in the unit circle we have:
$$\limsup_{N}S_N(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2}\cot\frac{\alpha}{4},\qquad \liminf_{N}S_N(\alpha) = -\frac{1}{2}\tan\frac{\alpha}{4}$$
and since we are free to assume $\alpha\in(0,2\pi)$, then $S_N(\alpha)$ always oscillates between a rather large positive value and a rather small negative value.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I will let indices start at 0. If $x$ is not a multiple of $2\pi$ then
$$S(x)_n = \Im \sum_{j=0}^n e^{ijx} = \Im \frac{e^{i(n+1)x} - 1}{e^{ix} - 1} \le \frac{ |e^{i(n+1)x}| + 1 }{ \left | e^{ix} - 1 \right| } \le \frac{2}{ \left| e^{ix} - 1 \right| },$$
which means $\liminf S(x)$ and $\limsup S(x)$ are finite. If $x$ is a multiple of $2\pi$ then $S(x)_n = 0$ so the same is true.